# Flickering in metal rendered view (MTKView)

Tags: swift, macos, gpu, metal, appkit

I'm trying to create an "infinite grid" for some kind of graphic software, similar to the one in Desmos or Geogebra. I want the view to be rendered using metal. My problem is that, although the code seems to be working fine, it often flickers.

[Here is a gif with the described behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gui2E.gif)

As you can see, in the first part is behaves normally, then is starts to "flicker"

Note that this doesn't happen when the redraw of the grid is triggered by a `scrollWheel` event, when the grid is zoomed.

## Brief explanation of what the code does

1. In the `draw()` function, I compute the number of dots that should be visible inside the view
2. I call the `drawPrimitives` function with the `instanceCount` parameters equal to the number of dots that should be visible
3. Inside my shaders file, I compute the position of each primitive using the `instance_id` attribute

I think the problem should be related to the way the view handles resize, since when the redraw is triggered by the zoom event everything works as intended. Also, don't think it is a performance issue, since fps is very high and stable.

[Here is the GitHub with the full code](https://github.com/mattia-marini/TikzUI)

I tried messing with the `isPaused` and `enableSetNeedsDisplay` attributes, but I can't implement a version where `isPaused = true` and `enableSetNeedsDisplay = false`.

The part that confuses me the most is that this seems to happen at random times, but again, performance seems not to ben an issue in my case...

How could avoid that annoying flickering effect while resizing window?

Here is my view class:

```
import AppKit
import MetalKit

class MetalView : MTKView {
    
    var queue : MTLCommandQueue!
    var pipelineState : MTLRenderPipelineState!
    
    private var spacing : Float = 10.0
    private var xoffset : Float = 0
    private var yoffset : Float = 0
    
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        
        self.queue = device?.makeCommandQueue()
        
        self.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
        
        self.colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        
        self.isPaused = true; self.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
        
        makePipeline()
        print("costructor")
        
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        drawGrid()
    }
    
    private func drawGrid(){
        
        guard let drawable = self.currentDrawable,
              let passDescriptor = self.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
              let commandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer(),
              let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: passDescriptor)
        else {
            print("errore")
            return
        }
        
        let infos = [Float(bounds.width), Float(bounds.height), xoffset, yoffset, spacing]
        
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(infos, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * infos.count, index: 0)
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 1,
                                     instanceCount: Int(
                                        (floor((infos[0] - xoffset) / spacing)+1) *
                                        (floor((infos[1] - yoffset) / spacing)+1)))
        
        renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        
        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
    }
    
    private func makePipeline() {
        
        guard let library = device?.makeDefaultLibrary() else {print("errore makePipeline"); return}
        
        let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertex_function")
        pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_function")
        pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        
        do {
            pipelineState = try device?.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineStateDescriptor)
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Errore nella creazione della pipeline")
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
        
    }
```

And here is my shaders file:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;


struct Fragment{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float pointSize [[point_size]] = 5.0f;
    float4 color;
};

vertex Fragment vertex_function (unsigned int instanceID [[instance_id]],
                                 constant float *parameters [[buffer(0)]])
{
    
    const float width = parameters[0];
    const float height = parameters[1];
    const float xoffset = parameters[2];
    const float yoffset = parameters[3];
    const float spacing = parameters[4];
    
    int xdots = floor((width - xoffset)/spacing) + 1;
    
    float non_normalized_x = xoffset + (instanceID % xdots) * spacing;
    float non_normalized_y = yoffset + (instanceID / xdots) * spacing;
    
    float normalized_x = non_normalized_x / width * 2 - 1;
    float normalized_y = non_normalized_y / height * 2 - 1;
    
    Fragment f;
    f.position = float4(normalized_x, normalized_y, 0, 1);
    
    return f;
}

fragment float4 fragment_function(Fragment in [[stage_in]])
{
    return float4(0.8,0.8,0.8,1);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you are using `MTKView` correctly. What you need to do is to implement `MTKViewDelegate` protocol and set that into your `MTKView`. By doing what you did, I think, you are basically taking over the draw loop in `MTKView` and interfering with it's drawables. Keep in mind that you can't present a drawable more than once, and that's why you might be getting flickering.

Comment: Post a [mre] in the question please.

Comment: @Spo1ler i'm not implementing a `MTKViewDelegate`, but i'm subclassing `MTKView` and overriding the `draw` function. By doing so the draw function should just be called whenever needed, or explicitly setting `setNeedsDisplay`... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. Problem was that while resizing the view layer got stretched automatically and then redrawn, creating that "jitterish" effect.
I found the solution in [this repository](https://github.com/trishume/MetalTest/tree/master). Basically I had to render the view synchronously, by adding the following line:

```
 presentsWithTransaction = true
```

then, in the `draw()` function, I had to use this 3 lines:

```
 commandBuffer.commit()
 commandBuffer.waitUntilScheduled()
 drawable.present()
```

to draw synchronously.
My code is in [this repo](https://github.com/mattia-marini/TikzUI)